# For Windows 10 app. Can I use WebView control with IE render engine (not EDGE)

Tags: windows, webview, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-edge

By default the WebView control, for Windows 10 apps, is used an EDGE rendering engine. Can I change the EDGE engine on an InternetExplorer engine for this control?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to use IE as an engine for Windows 10 apps for WebView.